# ng-model value is missing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to get a value from a textbox however field city's value is missing froom the logs, and some other fields are jumbled up. i checked the html form and it's fine. am i missing something?

here's the html form code:

```
  <form="myForm">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="MMID" ng-model="mmid" class="form-control" maxlength="9" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Card Number" ng-model="cardNumber" class="form-control" maxlength="11" />
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="First Name" ng-model="fname" class="form-control" maxlength="25">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Gender (M or F)" ng-model="gender" class="form-control" maxlength="1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <input type="text"  placeholder="Middle Name" ng-model="mname" class="form-control" maxlength="25">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Birthplace" ng-model="birthplace" class="form-control" maxlength="30">
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="lname" class="form-control" maxlength="25">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Citizenship" ng-model="citizenship" class="form-control" maxlength="30">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Birthdate (MM/DD/YYYY)" ng-model="bday" class="form-control" maxlength="8">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="SSS ID / TIN ID" ng-model="sssTinID" class="form-control" maxlength="20">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input  type="email"  placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="email" class="form-control" maxlength="30">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Company Name" ng-model="companyName" class="form-control" maxlength="30">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" ng-model="mobile" class="form-control" maxlength="15">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Company Address" ng-model="companyAddress" class="form-control" maxlength="30">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Address" ng-model="address" class="form-control" maxlength="60">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Work Title" ng-model="workTitle" class="form-control" maxlength="30">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <input type="text"  placeholder="City"  ng-model="city" class="form-control" maxlength="30">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <label for="sourceOfFunds">Source of Funds: </label>
       <select id="sourceOfFunds" ng-model="srcFunds" ng-change="showSelectValue(srcFunds)">
         <option>Employment</option>
         <option>Business</option>
         <option>Other</option>
       </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Zip Code" ng-model="zipcode" class="form-control" maxlength="10">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" placeholder="*If others, specify source of funds" ng-model="otherSrcFunds" class="form-control" maxlength="30">
    </div>
  </div>
```

here's the code for controller.js:

```
$scope.goNextandSave = function(mmid,cardNumber,fname,mname,lname,bday,email,mobile,address,city,zipcode,gender,birthplace,citizenship, sssTinID,companyName,companyAddress,workTitle, srcFunds, otherSrcFunds)
{
  console.log("srcFunds = " + srcFunds);
  console.log("fnamane = " + fname);
  console.log("mname = " + mname);
  console.log("lname = " + lname);

  console.log("bday = " + bday);
  console.log("email = " + email);
  console.log("mobile = " + mobile);

  console.log("address = " + address);
  console.log("city = " + city);
  console.log("zipcode = " + zipcode);

  console.log("gender = " + gender);
  console.log("birthplace = " + birthplace);
  console.log("citizenship = " + citizenship );

  console.log("sss = " + sssTinID);
  console.log("companyName = " + companyName);
  console.log("companyAddress = " + companyAddress);

  console.log("workTitle = " + workTitle);
}
```

and here's the output in the console.logs:

```
srcFunds = Business
controllers.js:131 fnamane = fname
controllers.js:132 mname = mname
controllers.js:133 lname = lname
controllers.js:135 bday = bdate
controllers.js:136 email = email@email.com
controllers.js:137 mobile = mobile
controllers.js:139 address = address
controllers.js:140 city = zip
controllers.js:141 zipcode = g
controllers.js:143 gender = bplace
controllers.js:144 birthplace = citizenship
controllers.js:145 citizenship = sss
controllers.js:147 sss = companyName
controllers.js:148 companyName = companyAddress
controllers.js:149 companyAddress = worktitle
controllers.js:151 workTitle = Business
```

Comment: Show us the code that calls goNextandSave.  You probably have a missing or misaligned parameter in there.  You should really consider using a hash to store and pass around the individual fields, ie. $scope.formData = {}... ng-model="formData.fname" and then your goNextandSave function can take a simple parameter of (formData).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `console.log("srcFunds = " + $scope.srcFunds);`? and remove the parameters of the function `goNextandSave `?

Comment: after double checking everything, apparently i was missing city parameter in goNextandSave ()